# Can I turn off "Sign in to download from the App Store"

Tags: mac, macos, mac-appstore, sleep-wake

Anyone know how to turn this off? I don't want my mac to run any processes I don't specifically ask for. I never use the app store except to update the OS, so I want to disable this (assuming it isn't part of a massive dependency) until the very minute I care to update. I don't need notifications at all. I know what's on my machine and I know when to update them. I just hate being harassed every time this machine wakes up and no, I don't want to always be signed in to anything.

Side note, when I restart or wake up my mac it usually chokes for an unreasonable amount of time until this app store notification pops up. Then it's fine. I recall Steve Jobs mocking the world by saying something like if you need a task manager you have failed... well, I need one because I don't know of any tool on mac that will profile everything that is currently running so I can identify what is making this thing torture me with spinning wheels for so long on start up. Pretty sure it's not me who failed here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well the slowness on startup isn't caused by the App Store. If you're really annoyed by this popup, then just log in. I just don't understand why you can't do that.

Comment: Does it matter why? It's my choice to not be logged in. It should also be my choice to disable nuisance programs from automatically running without my consent. And because needing a task manager is apparently a sign of failure, I can't determine if the app store is or is not what's causing the slowness. I assume so because the machine stops being slow as soon as that popup shows and I close it.

Comment: Ya well it should be my choice to stop apple from automatically downloading iOS Updates to my phone, but even if I delete it, it'll still re-download and remind me the next day. (Apple gets users to do what Apple wants). May I ask why you need a task manager? Are you trying to kill a specific process.

Comment: I feel I could benefit from being able to see what is currently running and what cpu expense is involved with each process. I don't feel the force quit menu gives an actual list of all running processes. FYI I am a software developer. I run a ton of high cpu programs and I do not need anything extra running at the same time. Unnecessary diversions like software notifications, phone syncs, etc, just interfere with development, which can sometimes be "crisis" and require immediate attention - like less than a minute immediate.

Comment: The decision to run an all mac workshop was not mine, and for the most part I feel the machine performs very well. Aside the fact that it seems to think I'm a 16 year old girl who wants huge glossy bouncing icons, text messages popping up on screen, and un-ending harassment trying to get me to buy things from an app store.

Comment: I use Activity Monitor and it's great at keeping track of CPU, memory and disk functions. Just be sure to show All Processes.

Comment: Thank you! I feel dumb for not knowing that existed, but unfortunately it's not an answer to this particular question, which I still want to know if disabling app store is possible. I'll make a new question asking specifically about monitoring programs so you can answer there and I will accept. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: here you go. thanks for your time. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220381/is-there-a-task-manager-for-mac-el-capitan