# Is there a task manager for OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, performance

Something's causing my Mac to bottleneck on startup and on wake. I'm curious if I can isolate this by leaving a monitor program running so I can see what's eating up the CPU.

How can I check CPU usage like Task Manager on Windows allows?

Comment: Is the built-in Activity Monitor not adequate?

Comment: Or more specialized: Xcode->Developer Tools->Instruments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **OS X** equivalent of *Windows Task Manager* is **Activity Monitor**, located in /Applications/Utilities/, or *type* **Activity Monitor** in **Spotlight**.

See Activity Monitor's internal Help: *Activity Monitor > Help > Activity Monitor Help*

For more information see Apple's Support Document: [Use Activity Monitor on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464)

Also, as mentioned by klanomath, for more specialized scenarios there is **Instruments** in **Xcode**. *(Xcode > Developer Tools > Instruments)*

Help for the Command Line version of Instruments, in a Terminal *type*: `man instruments`

Or see Apple's [Instruments User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

In a simpler way, you can also use the UNIX command `top` which you can enter in a command line to show the top process eating your memory or CPU.

To sort the process my memory usage, just use `top -o MEM` and if you want to sort the process by CPU usage, you can use `top -o CPU`.